# In XSL how to check datatype of attribute given in schema

Tags: xslt

I have XML that contains date values where type given in schema is not xs:date but user defined simple type as date_type.
In resulting XML I wanted to change the format of date say from "YYYY-MM-DD" to "YYYYMMDD" for all attribues having type as date_type.
Below link says that there is way to do but I was not able to compile stylesheet using attribute(*,type)
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-schemaawarexslt/#table2
My XML is:

```
<input>
<car mileage="15000" mfgDate="2012-12-31"/>
<battery mfgDate="2012-03-01" expiryDate="2014-12-31"/>
     ...
</input>
```

In my Schema files I have data type date_type as:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="date_type">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:length value="8"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

Also mfgDate and expiryDate are of date_type as:

```
<xsd:attribute name="mfgDate" type="sch:date_type"/>
<xsd:attribute name="expiryDate" type="sch:date_type"/>
```

Expected output is:

```
<input>
<car mileage="15000" mfgDate="20121231"/>
<battery mfgDate="20120301" expiryDate="20141231"/>
     ...
</input>
```

Is there a way to check the data type of attribute for all such types and do the string manipulation like:

```
<xsl:template match="attribute(*,sch:date_type)">
    <xsl:value-of select="translate(.,'-','')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Above line attribute(*,sch:date_type) is giving syntax error TransformerConfigurationException: Could not compile stylesheet.

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using?  Typed tests like these require a schema-aware XSLT 2.0 processor such as Saxon EE.

Comment: The XSLT processor that ships with IBM WebSphere's XML Feature (and which as of Websphere Application Server 8.5 just ships as part of the base prduct) also support XSLT 2.0.... and, yes, you need XSLT 2.0 to access type information.